# Time display format problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My object model has a attribute named "`start_at`" which is sotred in PostgreSQL database.

Inside the database table, the type of "`start_at`" is **"time without time zone"** and one object start_at value is e.g. **10:20:00**.

However, when I render this time value to my `index.html.haml` view by using 
`%td =myobj.start_at`, the view page always show "***Sat Jan 01 10:20:00 UTC 2000***" instead of ***10:20:00***.

How to get rid of it to show only 10:20:00 instead of the long string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about:

```
myobj.start_at.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

Check resource here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000392

Answer (score 3):

use `timeobj.strftime("%H:%M:%S")`

you can view all the options for `strftime` [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000392)

Comment: Well, ok, you answered first ;)

Comment: No, it does not work, my server give the error message "ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `strptime' for Time:Class)"